# Выборка из трёх таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы: notes, users и comments. Связи:
notes.author_id - users.id
comment.note_id - notes.id
При выборке заметок из notes нужно получить имя автора из users (c этим разобрался) И подсчитать количество комментариев к заметке. Как это сделать?

```
SELECT 
  notes.id,
  notes.title,
  notes.content,
  users.username
 -- COUNT(comments.id) AS comments_count
FROM 
  notes
INNER JOIN 
  users 
ON 
  (notes.author_id=users.id)
--???
ORDER BY 
  datetime 
DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю проще всего подзапросом, прямо в списке выборки, что бы не замножились записи и не писать group by.

```
SELECT notes.id,  notes.title,  notes.content,  users.username,
       (SELECT count(1) FROM comment WHERE comment.note_id=notes.id) AS comments_count
  FROM notes
  JOIN users ON notes.author_id=users.id
 ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Ой, спасибо большое! Не додумался я что-то насчёт вложенного запроса))